# Can I use xtrabackup to import a database without altering others?

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, xtrabackup

**Context:**

Each time a demo branch is built, I want to download a copy of the prod database and setup it onto the demo server. This way under the MySQL I have X database corresponding to X demos.

I achieved it using the `mysql_import` but it takes 3 ~ 5 minutes when importing the DB. So to speed up I wanna use `Xtrabackup`.

**Problem:**

The problem is that during the full backup, xtrabackup copies all the necessary files and also the `ib_logfile`files.

So let's say I want to import the database into database named `demo_1874`.

1. I do a full backup of the database, then I run `--prepare` twice on the same server, and I compress the result.
2. Download on the other server, uncompress all the backup files
3. Paste them under `/var/lib/mysql` which will override the other files (`ib_logfile`)
4. Rename the folder `original_db` to `demo_1874`

**Question**

- By copying files like `ib_logfile`, will it break all the other databases I have on this MySQL server (which I don't want this to happen) ?
- What are the other options using Xtrabackup to import a database among others without altering the others ?

Comment: You can minimize the risk as of first question if you gracefully stop the server before loading it as this may avoid breakage.

Comment: But I mean If I replace the `ib_logfile` from the server A into the server B which has different databases. Even if the server is stopped, it will corrupt the other databases no ?

Comment: I don't think it's going to work. if ib_logfile does kill it, replacing ibdata1 will. (unless all existing tables are MyISAM).

Answer (score 3):

What you need is partial backups.
`innodb_file_per_table=ON` is a prerequisite to make it work.

In your case procedure would be like following:

Take a partial backup from the production server

```
innobackupex --databases="mydatabase" /path/to/backup
```

On the destination server prepare the backup copy for export:

```
innobackupex --apply-log --export /path/to/backup
```

For each table repeat these steps:

create a new table with the same structure (get it from the production server with `mysqldump -t production` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE t`)

```
demo_1874> CREATE TABLE t (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Discard tablespace that InnoDB has

```
demo_1874> ALTER TABLE mydatabase.mytable DISCARD TABLESPACE; created.
```

Copy `t.*` files from partial backup to `/var/lib/mysql/demo_1874`, chown mysql:mysql them, and import the tablespace from the partial backup

```
demo_1874> ALTER TABLE t IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Consult http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html for more details.